# Create list of all sheet names in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

#### My goal

I have two spreadsheets, SpreadSheetA and SpreadSheetB.

I am trying to get a list of the names of all the sheets in SpreadSheetA and add it to the active sheet in SpreadSheetB.

#### My progress so far

I have the code done but keep getting an error message when I run it.

The error message is "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]" in reference to the line `range.setValues(sheetNameArray);`.

Here is my code:

```
function getSheetNamesAndAddToOtherSheet() {
  var spreadSheetAURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UNIQUE-ID-HERE/edit"; 
  var sheetNameArray = [];

  var spreadSheetsInA = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadSheetAURL).getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < spreadSheetsInA.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(spreadSheetsInA[i].getName());
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetNameArray.length, 1);
  range.setValues(sheetNameArray);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message hints at what's wrong: the `setValues` method expects "Object[][]" that is a **double** array of things. In Google Sheets, all ranges of data are represented as double arrays, such as `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. If there is one row, it's still a double array: `[[1, 2]]`. If it's one column: `[[1], [3]]`.

So you need this extra array dimension, essentially wrapping every sheet name in square brackets. This is done below, where I also used [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to process the array of sheets: this is cleaner and likely more efficient than using `push` in a `for` loop.

```
function getSheetNamesAndAddToOtherSheet() {
  var spreadSheetAURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UNIQUE-ID-HERE/edit"; 
  var sheetNameArray = [];

  var spreadSheetsInA = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadSheetAURL).getSheets();

  sheetNameArray = spreadSheetsInA.map(function(sheet) {
    return [sheet.getName()];
  });

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetNameArray.length, 1);
  range.setValues(sheetNameArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michelle!  Just a quick edit for your response above - the new line you added is missing `);` at the end of the `map` method

Answer (score 2):

Try the below...

```
function getSheetNamesAndAddToOtherSheet() {
  var spreadSheetAURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UNIQUE-ID-HERE/edit"; 
  var spreadSheetsInA = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadSheetAURL).getSheets();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < spreadSheetsInA.length; i++) {
    sheet.appendRow([spreadSheetsInA[i].getName()])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so clearly. Also, this appends rows to the bottom of data in the current sheet, while the OP wants the names to be placed at the top of the sheet.