# How can I dynamically build a formula to combine multiple tabs data to a consolidation tab from a list, the list changes

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I dynamically build a formula to combine multiple tabs data to a consolidation tab from a list

I have a google sheet
That contains multiple tabs of Currency Pairs
Each of these tabs has 200 ish rows of data that is summarized

I want to be able to do comparisons of different groupings of the Currency tabs

I have a formula that works if I manually enter the specific sheet names
=Query({'EURUSD-BASE'!B13:K213;'EURUSD-SL618'!B13:K213;’EURCAD-SL683’!B13:K213},"select * where Col1<>''order by Col4")

Data from this works exactly as I need it to.

However what I would like to do is have a list of SheetNames that automatically update this formula based upon the sheets selected.
All the Sheet names are pulled from a Reference Sheet using Data Validation to ensure that tab names are correct
[Pull Down list of Sheet Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQM9G.png)
Any ideas how I can do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pull out sheet names automatically without use of scripts.

If you want to use the script - try this topic:
[Create list of all sheet names in Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533701/create-list-of-all-sheet-names-in-google-apps-scripts)

If you want to use sheet names dynamically, you can use INDIRECT formula that allows to treat references as a string.
For example

```
INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B13:K212")
```

returns

```
'EURUSD-BASE'!B13:K213
```

when you put EURUSD-BASE into A1 cell and it can be used as a valid reference within other formulas.