# Google sheets: get a list of the sheet names giving a GS file url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying for many hours to get a script that returns the list of names of the sheets of a GS document after giving it the url of said document or the cell that contains said url in the document I am working on.
I previously found this proposal that I modified slightly but it doesn't work for me:
[Create list of all sheet names in Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533701/create-list-of-all-sheet-names-in-google-apps-scripts)

```js
function getSheetNamesFromOtherGSfile(otherGSfileURL) {
  var spreadSheetAURL = otherGSfileURL;
  var sheetNameArray = [];

  var spreadSheetsInA = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadSheetAURL).getSheets();

  sheetNameArray = spreadSheetsInA.map(function(sheet) {
    return [sheet.getName()];
  });

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetNameArray.length, 1);
  range.setValues(sheetNameArray);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does not work for you, please explain which error you are encountering. Please also show how you are calling this function.

Comment: Thank for your reply.

Error when I excute the code: Argument Not Valid: url 
getSheetNamesFromOtherGSfile @ Código.gs:5

I want call the function like in some cell put the formula

=getSheetNamesFromOtherGSfile(A1)
where A1 contents a google sheet file url

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) you cannot call `Spreadsheet.openById()` within a custom function in a cell.

The approach I recommend is to create a container-bound function, see [docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#create_a_bound_script). With these function, which can be called from a custom menu, there are none of those limitations.